# What do you think about a person that agrees too much on the PR suggestions?

Tags: pull-request

I had an interesting conversation with a colleague once about how he felt about agreeing too much with PR suggestions, he felt that people could think you don't know what you are doing.

At that moment I could only think about the time this other person put on reviewing my code and, even then sometimes I would obviously disagree, that often this kind of comment comes from the other person trying to find a common denominator on understanding.

What is your idea?

Answer (score 1):

I regularly challenge the feedback I get when I don't agree - naturally. Discussing feedback is one of the most important parts of the whole PR flow. You miss out on a lot of insight if you don't.

In addition I always offer to go through the feedback I give together because in debate you can get so much more out of it than just by written feedback.